# How can I check if treeUri is empty?

Tags: java, android, list, uri

I want to check if a treeUri has any files in it or if its empty, so I can delete the Folder. Ive tried listFiles but comes up with Landrodix.etc. and not the actual list. Thanks.

On Folder select

```
Intent intent = new 
Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
```

Activity Result

```
DocumentFile dfile =
DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri);
DocumentFile[] de = dfile.listFiles();
st = de.toString();
```

Comment: The simple approach is to pass the `Uri` that you get to `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()`, then call `listFiles()` on the `DocumentFile` that you get back, and see if the list is empty. For large trees, this query may be a bit slow to execute. There might be faster options using `DocumentsContract` directly.

Comment: Thanks, im kind of new to developing and i currently use Sketchware, cus i only have a phone to code. Its just straight Java, do you think you could provide a code sample of this cus   I cant piece it together. Also i was thinking maybe i could just use fileSize = file.length(); on the treeUri

Comment: So like this on Activity result, DocumentFile dfile =
DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri);
DocumentFile[] fileList = dfile.listFiles();
st = fileList.toString();
button2.setText(st);

Comment: Then i just get LandroidX DocumentFileProvider.DocumentFile:@ then numbers

Comment: `DocumentFile dfile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri); DocumentFile[] fileList = dfile.listFiles();` -- those steps seem fine. `fileList.length` will be 0 if the tree is empty.

Comment: @CommonsWare even when empty i still get this [Landroidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile;@c2cd987

Comment: That is the expected output of `toString()` called on a Java array, where the array is of type `DocumentFile`.

Comment: Just reiterating here im stilll kind of new to all this, what does that mean. And how do i get actual number of files/list of uri files. You siad it should return 0. Please code would be nice...

Comment: How do i get 0, please?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(muri); 
DocumentFile directory = 
DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri);
DocumentFile[] files = 
directory.listFiles();
double w3 =  
Double.parseDouble(Integer.toString
(files3.length));
```

feel free to use this code no credits required
it just .length